# C#. Wav-файл и цифровая обработка сигналов

Tags: c#, wav

Добрый день!

Написал программу, которая принимает wav-файл и разбивает его на заголовок и массив данных (`byte[] data`).

**Вопрос:** как из такого массива данных получить значения амплитуд и частот сигнала в определенный момент времени? Или дайте ссылку на статью, где хорошо объясняется, что из себя представляет этот массив данных. (Прошу не отправлять меня читать документацию формата `wav`).

Comment: Можно в [исходниках](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) покопаться. Или сразу взять готовое и использовать для своих нужд.

Comment: wav всего лишь контейнер, извлечённый массив данных вам особо не поможет, так как сами аудио-данные будут закодированны каким-либо кодеком, будь то pcm, gsm, mp3 и т.д. Лучше найти готовую библиотеку, которая может всё это прочитать, тот же NAudio например. А потом уже используя БПФ искать частоты и амплитуды.

Comment: @PrimusSingularis спасибо! Это то, что я хотел услышать. Тогда последний вопрос: в NAudio мне достаточно будет использовать `AudioFileReader`, чтобы получить `double[] signal` и этот сигнал пропустить через БПФ, я правильно Вас понял?